# JSR Bean Validation and multiple groups, AND vs OR

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, jsr330

Has anyone come across the need to have a constraint that is only applied when all group clauses are satisfied. In other words, for

```
@NotNull(groups= {Group1.class, Group2.class})
private Integer value;
```

The not null constraint is applied when either group is valid.

What if I want to apply a constraint when both groups are valid?

Having a custom group is not an option as there are many combinations of such groups in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might declare a [group sequence](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e971) containing all your groups and validate that sequence.